# Running a command before every execution of a script/program

Tags: windows, bash, unix

I'm using Bash on Windows and what I'm missing is a good IDE. I've tried running a GUI app with the following tutorial but it doesn't work well every time and it's frustrating.

What I want is to run the script that would copy the files from a folder on Windows into a folder on Unix subsystem, but only the files that are different. And same for the other direction (if I change something from terminal, to be updated in the Windows folder). I want that script to be run every time I call `./SOME_EXECUTABLE` in that folder. For the check weather the file was changed or not I can use `hg status` because I'm mostly working with Mercurial.

Is there a way to do this without making a separate shell script that would combine those calls? Something like a macro.

Comment: I think instead of writing such a script, you should setup a samba server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add an alias to `.bash_aliases` such as:

```
alias execute="./copyScript.sh && ./$1"
```

You can replace `./` with your scripts path
This runs the executable after your script has finished, and only if it finished successfuly.

It would be easier for you then writing a function in one of the `.rc` files
If you'd write a function called execute, in the future you might forget where   It was written, using an alias helps you avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a function in `.bashrc` to achieve your requirement, and run your required `script` that copies stuff from across machines as you needed. Assuming you have the script in place, lets say, e.g. `copyScript.sh` you can add a function like

```
function copyOnExecute() {
    ./copyScript.sh
    ./EXECUTABLE
}
```

This way you can call the function `copyOnExecute`, every time you want to run your executable.